# How do I calculate the coefficient of R square?

Tags: python

I'm trying to calculate the coefficient of R square using the formula below. This is a statistical means of determining how well our regression equation fits the data provided.

```
R^2 = { ( 1 / N ) * Σ [ (xi - x) * (yi - y) ] / (σx * σy ) }^2
```

Use this to plug in the last equation above

```
σx = sqrt [ Σ ( xi - x )2 / N ] 
σy = sqrt [ Σ ( yi - y )2 / N ]
```

xi is the value of x from the dataset
yi is the value of y from the dataset
x is the average value of x data
y is the average of y data
n is the number of data points in the dataset
σx is the standard deviation of the x values
σy is the standard deviation of the y values

Below is my code. I get 1589, when I believe it should be around 0 to 1. Maybe my code is incorrect somewhere. Don't worry about the xi and yi.

```
sum3 = (x[i] - xaverage)
sum4 = (y[i] - yaverage)
sum5 = math.sqrt(sum3 * sum3)
sum6 = math.sqrt(sum4 * sum4)
var1 = (1 / len(x and y)* (sum3) * (sum4))
var2 = sum5 / len(x and y) 
var3 = sum6 / len(x and y)
var4 = var2 * var3 * var2 * var3
Rsquare = var1 / var4
print("This is the coefficient of R square:", Rsquare)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3? Also, what values do those variables have before that code is run? Try printing them and posting their values.

Comment: Can you use scipy? Saves you from reinventing the wheel... http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html